# Standard SQL command to get current RDBMS

Tags: sql

Is there any standard sql command that can show you the current RDBMS and version?

The reason for this question is that I am using a CMS remotely that use a SQL database, but I don't know which RDBMS is being used, so I thought maybe there is standard SQL command to print it, something similar to SQL server's `@@version`

Comment: As far as I know, there is not

Comment: @MusuNaji . . . Basically, you need to test a bunch of different commands to see which database it is.

Comment: As a quick guide you can use [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) to get queries for a log of DBMS (all they support). When you don't enter your own query, the default query will be one that retrieves version information. Some may share a query though. In such a case you'd have to try some additional DBMS specific queries to get a final decision.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but since there is no standard sql query or function to show the RDBMS, I will post the queries/functions/vars used to identify it.

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT @@version;

-- Postgres, mysql, mariadb
SELECT version();

-- Oracle
SELECT * FROM v$version;

-- sqlite
select sqlite_version();
```

Please pay attention that `Mysql` and `Sqlite` will show only the version and will not include engine name in contrast to other RDBMS.

Comment: Before you can run a query, you need to connect to the database, don't you? So are you implying that you connect to a database and you don't know which RDBMS you connected to?

Comment: yes, if you read my question, I am accessing a CMS that is already configured to connect to some database engine, and I want to know which database engine it is using a sql query because this CMS offers a user interface to execute queries.